# How to show info window without clicking on marker

Tags: android, google-maps, maps, infowindow

Actually I have a screen where on top half screen there is a map and on the other half there is a list of address and when click on any particular list item map show the marker of that particular address but the thing is I want to show info window too by clicking on list item. here is the screen shot of my work.

I want info window above that blue marker but I cant use onMarkerClickListener.

[image: map]

I have tried using infoWindowAdapter but I guess it is not the solution
[image]
Can anyone help?

Comment: Try this : marker.showInfoWindow();

Comment: @Haresh can be only done in OnMarkerClickListener

Answer (score 3):

Save references of added markers in an array:

```
List<Marker> mMarkers = new ArrayList<Marker>();

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...

    mMarkers.add(googleMap.addMarker(marker));

    ...

}
```

Then create a listener for your `ListView`:

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new ListView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        mMarkers.get(position).showInfoWindow();
    }
});
```

**Note:**

Your markers will have to be added in the correct order, i.e. the same order as `ListView`'s items.

Comment: how you get mMarker.get(position).showInfoWindow in the function of onItemClick ? i don't get any option like this after get(position) @user3249477

Comment: @user3651574 make sure you follow my code. You need mMarkers to be a class variable (declared outside any method) and you need to add Markers there, then you will be able to call `showInfoWindow()`. Not sure what's your problem. Post some code maybe.

Comment: Should be mMarkers.get(position).showInfoWindow() instead of mMarker.get(position).showInfoWindow()